# Rest API LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

Here's the overview of the dependencies that I am using for creating a REST API. When executing as mvn spring-boot:run, I am getting an error saying that "unknown lifecycle phase mvn".I am a newbie in spring-boot framework.What does that mean?As mvn: clean and mvn:install are building successfully.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven_1</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven_1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the error details on the console

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven_1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.897 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-12T17:40:02+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

The main class that I am using is as follows:

```
package maven_1;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);

    }

}
```

Comment: you are using terminal or on IDE?

Comment: Eclipse IDE @AmerQarabsa

Comment: It looks to me that you're running `mvn mvn spring-boot:run` in stead of `mvn spring-boot:run`. How do you run it in Eclipse exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This error means maven cannot find a valid goal, if you are using IDE to run mvn will be run by default so you only need to specify the goal, in your goal just type spring-boot:run

Also you can go to terminal and execute mvn spring-boot:run

if you have main method which run the spring app (must have "SpringApplication.run([class annotated with SpringBootApplication].class, args)", you can run the class which has this method as java application and spring boot will run as well.

Comment: if I directly run the main class,then I am getting a java.net.bindException.And if I directly do spring-boot:run on my IDE then also I am getting the bind and LifecyclePhaseException @AmerQarabsa

Comment: your main class is annotated with @SpringBootApplication ?